Generating Doxygen for a software component inside big monorepo
I work with a project with "big" monorepo of mostly C++ code.
It is organized into multiple components inside, able to link/call each other.
If I generate single Doxygen for everything documentation becomes overwhelming and not focused.
If I generate Doxygen for each component it is getting incomplete with things like call graphs missing calls to the code from other components.
Is there "better way" or "other tool" where documentation would focus on single software component while correctly referencing "dependencies of it"?

Which version of doxygen are you using. Did you read up on the tag file possibilities? With tag files call graphs might not be complete though.

i can use even the latest, but seems the problem is that references "outside of project" are not processed at all, i.e. doxygen does not assume anything about calls outside (which seems to be good idea in hindsight), but this sabotages "good documentation for a component being a subdirectories of bigger project"

Don't specify "latest" as version but the version reported by doxygen -v. Did you try to create for the subdirectories of a bigger project the tag files and used these on other places?
